# How to use t-if for string odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I would like to show the value of the `o.employee_id.name` variable inside a cell table only when it has a specific value. I tried like this but I get a syntax error:

```
<t t-if="o.employee_id.name=='naswar'">
    <td>
        <span t-field="o.employee_id.name"/>
    </td>
</t>
```

Comment: which types error generate? Please describe in your question. Because in your code not any error. Your code is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your syntax error is in other part of the code. If you print a empty cell in order to not break the table structure would be much better. Try this:

```
<td>
    <t t-if="o.employee_id">
        <t t-if="o.employee_id.name == 'naswar'">
            <span t-field="o.employee_id.name"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also apply condition with the html tag

If condition is true, span will be displayed
else < td > will be empty

```
<td>
    <span t-if="o.employee_id.name == 'naswar'" t-field="o.employee_id.name"/>
</td>
```